# SASS/SCSS - Error: $color: currentColor is not a color

Tags: css, sass

I have some issue when I want to generate Colors it show me an error messages
contain

> "Error: $color: currentColor is not a color."??

I dont know where this color coming from maybe the function that convert hex to rgb??

**My Full Code :**

```
// Function to Convert Hex Color to RGB Color

@function hexToRGB($hex) {
  @return red($hex), green($hex), blue($hex);
}

// Color Variables

$transparent:    transparent        !default;
$current:        currentColor       !default;
$white:          #fff               !default;

// Color Map

$shades: () !default;
$shades: map-merge(
    (
        "transparent":    $transparent,
        // The problem is Here it said :
        // currentColor is not a color.
        // Why??
        "current":        $current,
        "white":          $white,
    ),
    $shades
);

// Global Color Map

$colors: () !default;
$colors: map-merge(
    (
        "shades":    $shades,
    ),
    $colors
);

@each $name, $value in $colors {
    @each $shade, $color in $value {
        .color-#{$shade} {
            --color-example1: rgba(#{hexToRGB($color)}, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

**The Result that I want to get after compiling to CSS :**

```
.color-transparent {
  --color-example1: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

.color-current {
  --color-example1: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
}

.color-white {
  --color-example1: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
}
```

Comment: Is `currentColor` supposed to be a variable?  It never appears to be declared or defined...

Comment: I want to generate it as a color class like tailwindCSS

Comment: `--tw-gradient-stops: var(--tw-gradient-from), currentColor, var(--tw-gradient-to, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0))`

Comment: As @AlexanderNied points out, `currentColor` has no value assigned to it, so you're trying to pass a non-color to rgba.

Comment: How can I pass **255, 255, 255** to current *value**

Comment: like this `.color-current {
  --color-example1: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
}`

Comment: @AlexanderNied [currentColor](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-color-3/#currentcolor)

Comment: @theking2 - thanks for teaching me something new about CSS today-- this was enough info for me to [posit an answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70990728/6831341).

Answer (score 1):

*(Thanks to [user theking2](https://stackoverflow.com/users/718960/theking2) for [enlightening me regarding `currentColor`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64959198/sass-scss-error-color-currentcolor-is-not-a-color?noredirect=1#comment125495105_64959198).)*

I imagine this is related to [this closed SCSS bug ticket](https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/2907) in which they were wondering why they couldn't use `currentColor` in a sass `rgba`.  [This comment from one of the contributors](https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/2907#issuecomment-696228428) explains why this is not possible:

> This will not be possible in Sass, because currentColor is a variable calculated by the browser at run-time. As a pre-processor, Sass cannot know the value of currentColor, and can't adjust it using color functions. Your solution is the best I can think of at this point, besides using JS to do the calculations live in the browser and override your style sheet.
>
> When browsers implement the CSS Color Module Level 5 built-in color functions, that should also make it possible in plain CSS.

My *guess* is that this limitation is what prevents you from storing in a sass logical construct like a `map`.  You *might* be able to achieve what you are attempting using a CSS variable to store `currentColor` and putting that CSS variable in a SCSS variable, but I don't have a high degree of confidence on that.

I don't know for *certain* that this is the issue, but it seems likely to me.  Hopefully others in the SO community can verify or refute this with greater confidence.